# How to extract file from wrapped Jar in Java

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

The file (exe) is located inside JAR file, which was wrapped to EXE using Launch4j.

**My executable (JAR file wrapped in EXE):**

```
myProgram.exe
```

**Executable location**

```
myProgram.exe/program.jar/resources/sub-program.exe
```

How to run (or extract to temp directory) sub-program.exe and run it with parameters? `sub-program.exe -f -q`

If the sub-program was a file in temp, I could run it as:

```
String exeLocation = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "sub-program.exe";
String params = " -f -q";    
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", exeLocation + params);
```

How to extract file from wrapped Jar file ? I guess there is no way to run it inside wrapped Jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `InputStream` for resource in classpath, by something like `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/sub-program.exe")`.  You can read from the stream and create a file at any place you like (e.g. under temp directory as you hinted), and execute it.

Comment: Nice idea, could you post example please ? I've done it by really funny way to get bytes from sub-program.exe and then write them using FOS, but I guess there is better way than this.

Comment: that's the standard way.  There maybe some utils out there that can save you some boilerplate codes, like using Apache Commons IO, `IOUtils.copy(inputStreeam, yourFos)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run it from inside the jar programmatically? If not, you could just extract it manually beforehand with winzip (a jar is basically just a zip file).

I should note though that what you're trying to do is really odd.

Comment: Yes programmatically sure, I would like **not** to have the `sub-program.exe` visible to users (so when needed, it should extract it to temporary directory, and delete once the process is done.